# Rails: How can i add elements in application.html.erb layout instead of typing hard coded html element?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, element

How can i add elements in application.html.erb layout instead of typing hard coded html element ?

Is it possible to do this like we can do this in cakephp?
http://book.cakephp.org/view/1081/Elements

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like Rails Partials or helpers

Comment: What is helper?
How can i use helper?

Any example?
Are the var1 and var2 optional(locals)?

    <%= render :partial => 'nav', :locals => { :var1 => 'someval', :var2 => someobj } %>

Answer (score 0):

You could use helpers for small snippets or even partials for larger html chunks.  The cakepho element looks more similar to partials.  In rails you would have a partial for rendering a component like a nav in _nav.html.erb and it may require a few local variables to render.  In your application.html.erb you would render the partial:

```
<%= render :partial => 'nav', :locals => { :var1 => 'someval', :var2 => someobj } %>
```

This would be a great resource for you to read: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html

Answer (score 0):

Helpers are ruby methods you write to help create views. Here's a useful one:

```
def sentence_links objects, label_method = :name
  objects.map { |o| link_to(o.send(label_method), o) }.to_sentence.html_safe
end
```

And the in your views you can call `sentence_links Player.limit(3)` to output:

```
<a href="/players/15692665">Pearlie Gulgowski</a>, <a href="/players/34801824">Mr. Tommie O'Conner</a>, and <a href="/players/44139906">Wyman Schumm</a>
```